# Retrieving EXM Automated send data

Tags: xdb, exm

Is there a way to retrieve the data that was sent via automated messages in EXM? Specifically I would like:

- Contact ID
- Timestamp
- Message ID
- Tokens
- Message send status

I have checked in the xDB shards and the closest thing I can find is to query interactions by the Email Sent event. But this only provides the Contact ID, Message ID, and Timestamp. It doesn't provide the tokens or the status.